# One user reports bunched text in IE9 when viewing our public facing Sharepoint 2010 website

Tags: 2010

A user says:  "There is a problem every time I try to use your website. The first page is fine but whenever I page down all the text is just one mass of black type totally unreadable."   She says it only happens on our site.
I've asked her for a screenshot: http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/4905/bunchedtext.png. She is using IE9 and I cant replicate it. 
Does any one have any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some people experience issues on many websites in IE9 due to graphics drivers or Add-ins - there's links to a few different [Microsoft KB articles](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/ie9-text-overlaps/2d2419c8-a15c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).

**Step 1**: Please try the steps provided in the below articles which might help you.

WebPages do not display correctly in Internet Explorer 9
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2404821

Some Web sites may not behave as expected in Internet Explorer
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197

**Step 2**: Disable one add-on at a time and check if any add-on is causing this issue. You may enable them back after checking.

Refer: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Tips-for-solving-problems-with-Internet-Explorer

**Step 3**: Reset internet explorer and check.
Refer: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings-in-Internet-Explorer-9